# Inferring a partial type of a constant object

Tags: typescript

Let's say I've got a function that expects a certain interface

```
interface Foo {
  foo: number;
  bar: number;
  baz?: number;
  buz?: number;
}

const doFoo = (params: Foo) => { /* ... */ };
```

I also have some constant that contains default values for a subset of `Foo`:

```
const BASE_PROPERTIES = {
  foo: 42,
  baz: 9001,
};

doFoo({
  ...BASE_PROPERTIES,
  bar: -1000
});
```

This works fine. But I'm wondering if there's a way that I can signify that `BASE_PROPERTIES` contains some parts of `Foo`. Both to provide intellisense when editing, and make it clear what the constant is used for. Essentially an automated `Pick<>`.

I could do

```
const BASE_PROPERTIES: Partial<Foo> = { /* ... */ }
```

However that will mean that using it in the spread gives an error for `foo` because `Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'`. I could `as any` or `as Foo` it, but that trades convenience for risk in the event that I actually forgot to include `foo`.

Likewise, I could use `pick`

```
const BASE_PROPERTIES: Pick<Foo, 'foo' | 'baz'> = { /* ... */ }
```

But that requires me to keep it updated as I go (a bit cumbersome, not particularly DRY for very large objects), and won't give me intellisense as I'm adding further properties, kind of defeating half the point of adding it in the first place.

Is there a way to hint to typescript, that an object should follow the schema of an interface, but that it should figure out how the const actually fits the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`satisfies`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47920) operator introduced in [Typescript 4.9](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9/#satisfies)

```
const BASE_PROPERTIES = {
  foo: 42,
  baz: 9001,
} satisfies Partial<Foo>
```

This will make sure that `BASE_PROPERTIES` *satisfies* the type `Partial<Foo>` while still inferring the literal type.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIyYBcyIArgLYBG0A3PstXFKRTfY8wF4D8bVWlAYFq5PgI7DcAX1y4E6EAGcwyACboMWALzIAFAAcWcSstLaAlMh0A+HMgD0AKmQA6D8mePkMhgqVVZAAhAEEAZQBRAH0ABQAlAHlYyPiAFQBJSPCbHEYidFIAFgAmABouOG5SAE4ABjqARgqZZGU4MGBlGGAIZWRYlk64ABsAHm1beU1tfTwCDzcwqLiklPSs8IrRFlIAWkaGutlLOiA)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can have a small utility function to do so. Something like

```
function createBaseProps<K extends keyof Foo>(props: Pick<Foo, K>) {
  return props
}
```

you should get intellisense and type checks

```
const BASE_PROPERTIES = createBaseProps({
  foo: 123,
})
```

and be able to merge the result with your `doFoo` example